# Lightgbm GPU Installation for Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, boost, cmake, pip

1st try-) I installed CMake, Mingw, Boost and already had VS 2017 Community version.
I installed it successfully by using [this](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/GPU-Windows.html) guide. I even tested it on Git Bash and it works. But I guess that doesn't work with Python? Because i cant import and use it on Python IDLE, Notebook etc.

2nd try-)Also, i installed it with VS by using [this](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation-Guide.html) guide. 
It says
`The .exe file will be in LightGBM-master/windows/x64/Release folder.`
I guess this guide is for VS users, not for me?

3rd try-) `pip install lightgbm --install-option=--gpu`
Gives me error:`Exception: Please install CMake first`
I already had CMake, and added CMake into both system and user PATHs.

> C:\Program Files\CMake\bin

Also gives warnings about Boost variable, but in 1st try, i was able to install lightgbm with Boost.

LightGBM_compilation.txt shows the error in further detail:

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.17134.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27026.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27026.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
-- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
-- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenMP_C: -openmp (found version "2.0") 
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -openmp (found version "2.0") 
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "2.0")  
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_2_2
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_2_2 - not found
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_2_1
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_2_1 - not found
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_2_0
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_2_0 - not found
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_1_2
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_1_2 - found
-- Found OpenCL: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.0/lib/x64/OpenCL.lib (found version "1.2") 
-- OpenCL include directory:C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.0/include CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:97 (find_package):   Policy CMP0074 is not set: find_package uses <PackageName>_ROOT variables.   Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0074" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Environment variable Boost_ROOT is set to:

    C:\boost\boost_1_69_0

  For compatibility, CMake is ignoring the variable. This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Boost version: 1.69.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   system
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/dogus/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-1uszztyz/lightgbm/build_cpp Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 4/5/2019 10:42:58 AM. Project "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets). Project "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj" (1) is building "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets). PrepareForBuild:   Creating directory "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\". C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(399,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj] Creating directory "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\". InitializeBuildStatus:   Creating "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified. CustomBuild:   Checking Build System   CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/dogus/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-1uszztyz/lightgbm/build_cpp/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date. FinalizeBuildStatus:   Deleting file "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".   Touching "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\ZERO_CHECK.lastbuildstate". Done Building Project "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (default targets). PrepareForBuild:   Creating directory "_lightgbm.dir\Release\". C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(399,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj] Creating directory "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\Release\". Creating directory "_lightgbm.dir\Release\_lightgbm.tlog\". InitializeBuildStatus:   Creating "_lightgbm.dir\Release\_lightgbm.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified. CustomBuild:   Building Custom Rule C:/Users/dogus/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-1uszztyz/lightgbm/compile/CMakeLists.txt CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/dogus/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-1uszztyz/lightgbm/build_cpp/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date. ClCompile:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\CL.exe /c /I"C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\compute\include" /I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\include" /IC:\boost\boost_1_69_0 /I"C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\include" /nologo /W4 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /MP /O2 /Ob2 /Oi /Ot /Oy /GL /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D NDEBUG /D USE_SOCKET /D BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB /D USE_GPU /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\"" /D _lightgbm_EXPORTS /D _WINDLL /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /openmp /Fo"_lightgbm.dir\Release\\" /Fd"_lightgbm.dir\Release\vc141.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\c_api.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\lightgbm_R.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\application\application.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\boosting\boosting.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\boosting\gbdt.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\boosting\gbdt_model_text.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\boosting\gbdt_prediction.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\boosting\prediction_early_stop.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\io\bin.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\io\config.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\io\config_auto.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\io\dataset.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\io\dataset_loader.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\io\file_io.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\io\json11.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\io\metadata.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\io\parser.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\io\tree.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\metric\dcg_calculator.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\metric\metric.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\network\linker_topo.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\network\linkers_mpi.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\network\linkers_socket.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\network\network.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\objective\objective_function.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\treelearner\data_parallel_tree_learner.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\treelearner\feature_parallel_tree_learner.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\treelearner\gpu_tree_learner.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\treelearner\serial_tree_learner.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\treelearner\tree_learner.cpp" "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\src\treelearner\voting_parallel_tree_learner.cpp" c_api.cpp   lightgbm_R.cpp   application.cpp   boosting.cpp   gbdt.cpp gbdt_model_text.cpp   gbdt_prediction.cpp   prediction_early_stop.cpp  bin.cpp   config.cpp   config_auto.cpp   dataset.cpp   dataset_loader.cpp   file_io.cpp   json11.cpp   metadata.cpp   parser.cpp   tree.cpp   dcg_calculator.cpp   metric.cpp   linker_topo.cpp   linkers_mpi.cpp   linkers_socket.cpp   network.cpp   objective_function.cpp   data_parallel_tree_learner.cpp   feature_parallel_tree_learner.cpp   gpu_tree_learner.cpp   serial_tree_learner.cpp   tree_learner.cpp   voting_parallel_tree_learner.cpp Link:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\Release\lib_lightgbm.dll" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\lib\x64\OpenCL.lib" "C:\boost\boost-build\lib\libboost_filesystem.a" "C:\boost\boost-build\lib\libboost_system.a" kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:"C:/Users/dogus/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-1uszztyz/lightgbm/compile/Release/lib_lightgbm.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:/Users/dogus/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-1uszztyz/lightgbm/compile/Release/lib_lightgbm.lib" /MACHINE:X64  /machine:x64 /DLL _lightgbm.dir\Release\c_api.obj  
_lightgbm.dir\Release\lightgbm_R.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\application.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\boosting.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\gbdt.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\gbdt_model_text.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\gbdt_prediction.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\prediction_early_stop.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\bin.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\config.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\config_auto.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\dataset.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\dataset_loader.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\file_io.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\json11.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\metadata.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\parser.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\tree.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\dcg_calculator.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\metric.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\linker_topo.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\linkers_mpi.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\linkers_socket.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\network.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\objective_function.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\data_parallel_tree_learner.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\feature_parallel_tree_learner.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\gpu_tree_learner.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\serial_tree_learner.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\tree_learner.obj   _lightgbm.dir\Release\voting_parallel_tree_learner.obj   c_api.obj : MSIL .netmodule or module compiled with /GL found; restarting link with /LTCG; add /LTCG to the link command line to improve linker performance
     Creating library C:/Users/dogus/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-1uszztyz/lightgbm/compile/Release/lib_lightgbm.lib and object C:/Users/dogus/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-1uszztyz/lightgbm/compile/Release/lib_lightgbm.exp gpu_tree_learner.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void
__cdecl boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(char const *,char const *,class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > &,class std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,struct _Mbstatet> const &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem@boost@@YAXPEBD0AEAV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@AEBV?$codecvt@_WDU_Mbstatet@@@5@@Z) [C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj] gpu_tree_learner.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void
__cdecl boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &,class std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,struct _Mbstatet> const &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem@boost@@YAXPEB_W0AEAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBV?$codecvt@_WDU_Mbstatet@@@5@@Z) [C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj] gpu_tree_learner.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::filesystem::file_status __cdecl boost::filesystem::detail::status(class boost::filesystem::path const &,class boost::system::error_code *)" (?status@detail@filesystem@boost@@YA?AVfile_status@23@AEBVpath@23@PEAVerror_code@system@3@@Z) [C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj] gpu_tree_learner.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "bool
__cdecl boost::filesystem::detail::create_directories(class boost::filesystem::path const &,class boost::system::error_code *)" (?create_directories@detail@filesystem@boost@@YA_NAEBVpath@23@PEAVerror_code@system@3@@Z) [C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj] gpu_tree_learner.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,struct _Mbstatet> const & __cdecl boost::filesystem::path::codecvt(void)" (?codecvt@path@filesystem@boost@@SAAEBV?$codecvt@_WDU_Mbstatet@@@std@@XZ) [C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj] gpu_tree_learner.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class boost::filesystem::path & __cdecl boost::filesystem::path::make_preferred(void)" (?make_preferred@path@filesystem@boost@@QEAAAEAV123@XZ) [C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj] C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\Release\lib_lightgbm.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals [C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj] Done Building Project "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj" (default target) (1) -> "C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (default target) (2) -> (PrepareForBuild target) ->    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(399,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(399,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj" (default target) (1) -> (Link target) ->    gpu_tree_learner.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(char const *,char const
*,class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > &,class std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,struct _Mbstatet> const &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem@boost@@YAXPEBD0AEAV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@AEBV?$codecvt@_WDU_Mbstatet@@@5@@Z) [C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj] gpu_tree_learner.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void
__cdecl boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &,class std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,struct _Mbstatet> const &)" (?convert@path_traits@filesystem@boost@@YAXPEB_W0AEAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBV?$codecvt@_WDU_Mbstatet@@@5@@Z) [C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj] gpu_tree_learner.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::filesystem::file_status __cdecl boost::filesystem::detail::status(class boost::filesystem::path const &,class boost::system::error_code *)" (?status@detail@filesystem@boost@@YA?AVfile_status@23@AEBVpath@23@PEAVerror_code@system@3@@Z) [C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj] gpu_tree_learner.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "bool
__cdecl boost::filesystem::detail::create_directories(class boost::filesystem::path const &,class boost::system::error_code *)" (?create_directories@detail@filesystem@boost@@YA_NAEBVpath@23@PEAVerror_code@system@3@@Z) [C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj] gpu_tree_learner.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,struct _Mbstatet> const & __cdecl boost::filesystem::path::codecvt(void)" (?codecvt@path@filesystem@boost@@SAAEBV?$codecvt@_WDU_Mbstatet@@@std@@XZ) [C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj] gpu_tree_learner.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class boost::filesystem::path & __cdecl boost::filesystem::path::make_preferred(void)" (?make_preferred@path@filesystem@boost@@QEAAAEAV123@XZ) [C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj] C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\compile\Release\lib_lightgbm.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals [C:\Users\dogus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1uszztyz\lightgbm\build_cpp\_lightgbm.vcxproj]

    2 Warning(s)
    7 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:16.81
```

Comment: Please, do not format logs as *blockquote*. It is very hard to understand the log which loses *newlines*. Format logs as a *code* instead (with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button).

Comment: Okay, I'll edit it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was I got the boost files from this guide, but It wasn't for python installation that I wanted.
https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/GPU-Windows.html

And that boost file didn't have this library /lib64-msvc-14.1
I installed boost_1_69_0-msvc-14.1-64.exe, which I got from [here](https://bintray.com/boostorg/release/boost-binaries/1.69.0#files/1.69.0/binaries).

I included boost arguments and it worked!

```
pip install lightgbm --install-option=--gpu --install-option="--boost-root=C:/local/boost_1_69_0" --install-option="--boost-librarydir=C:/local/boost_1_69_0/lib64-msvc-14.1"
```

I was also having the Exception below everytime i tried pip install. If anyone is having the same problems, I hope this solution works for them.

```
Exception: Please install CMake first
```